# Zoom in effect on body background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the background image of my body to zoom in on page load. The following is the code i have.

CSS:

```
body, html { 
    font-size: 100%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;   
    background-image: url(bg.jpg); 
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all ease-in 5s;   

}
```

JQuery:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {         
          $(document.body).css("background-size", "140%");
      });
```

I'm trying to change the `background-size` property of the image on page load. but this is not working. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is:

```
html, body {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200") top center no-repeat;
    animation: animateBg forwards 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes animateBg{
    from { background-size: 200px; }
    to { background-size: 100%; }
}
```

Note: the image is just a placeholder, you can change it as well as the background-size property of the animateBg keyframe animation (and anything else you need). In case you are not aware of [forwards](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp).

Make sure to take a short while and read about [CSS Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), very convenient to be able to leverage CSS first when choosing between jQuery and CSS.

Let me know if this works for you, otherwise we can work on an improved answer that suits you better :)

Comment: Is there a way that i can continue this animation , or restart the animation once it is finished?

Comment: You can restart it by replacing 'forwards' with a different animation fill attribute like 'linear'

Comment: Just now found out that there is something called `animation-iteration-count: infinite` . We can use this attribute to repeat the animation forever.

Comment: that is true, it all depends on how you wish to approach it as you can play with more animation attributes and arrange them as needed

Comment: The link of jsfiddle doesn't work... Please make sure that your link works properly otherwise don't put any link here..ok

Comment: @JafferWilson thanks for noticing, but I don't know what happened to my jsFiddle... must have been on jsFiddle's side either ways the link is fixed now, I will leave it up to you to give me back that 1 up

Comment: My friend, its ok about your link, still I want to tell that your answer isn't relevant as the question was asked related to jQuery and you have used CSS...Refer to the answer of Mr. Roshan Padole. He used the jQuery where you have used CSS....PLease take a note of it ...

Comment: I understand what you mean to say and I assessed that his approach was better answered via CSS. The reason for this is not because it cannot be achieved in jQuery, is the fact that CSS delivers a relatively crisper animation than jQuery which translates to a better user experience, especially when scaling up. I do not disagree with jQuery but my answer also highlights that, for this case, CSS is more appropriate. If the OP wants a jQuery only answer I can provide one, or he can accept one of the already given. In the end it is their choice to pick what is most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Hope this will resolve your query

Just a simple `jquery` animation play

```
$("body").animate({
    "background-size" : "180px"
},2000);
```

Try this for live demo http://jsfiddle.net/g2ef7gc4/25/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("body").animate({
    "background-size", "140%"
},20000, function() { alert(); });
```

see example at [background zoom effect](http://app4pc.com)

Comment: The animation is happening actually , when i inspect element i can see the background size changing slowly , but it is only reflecting in the end when the thing is complete

Comment: It seems like i have to add 'linear' as a parameter since the default is swing. But it is giving an error `Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

Comment: its much easier to leverage CSS using keyframes, but to your point he should be using 'forwards' rather than linear

Comment: You have written the code wrongly. See, friend your code should be like this " background-size" : "140px.". An d the link you have given doesn't make any sense. Please take a note of it ....ok...............              Are you trying to promote your website?...

Answer (score 1):

here it is the Jquery function for your code. With delay and callback

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').animate({ backgroundSize: '135%'
    }, 2000, 'linear', function () {
        console.log("called");
    });

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not making that zoom effect inside the css?

```
body, html { 
    font-size: 100%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;   
    background-image: url(bg.jpg); 
    background-size: 140%;
    transition: all ease-in 5s;   
}
```

Comment: because i want it to zoom in slowly after the page is loaded. That i why transition is used. If i use it in css directly it will give the zoomed image on page load which is not i want

Answer (score -1):

@sooraj just set height and width as like demo

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {         
          $(document.body).css("background-size", "140%");
      });
```

```css
body, html { 
    font-size: 100%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;   
    background-image: url(//images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg); 
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all ease-in 5s;   
        height:500px;
    width:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: or your project on live server give me like i will check it